# Isn't .NET's integer just simply based on two's complement system?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx):

> > Int32 values are represented in 31 bits, with the thirty-second bit used as a sign bit. **Positive values are represented by using sign-and-magnitude representation.** Negative values are in two's complement representation.

Isn't it true that the representation of positive values using [sign-and-magnitude system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) is identical to the representation of positive values using [two's complement system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)?

So shouldn't it have been rewritten as: *"Int32 values (regardless of positive or negative) are represented in two's complement representation"*,

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No i dont think so, the whole reason for two's complement representation to exist is to support basic operations over negative values. 10000001 == -127, 00000001 == 1. positive int values are not represented using the two's complement system

Comment: yes they are,  when you are considering positive numbers you have to be aware that the highest bit does not mean "more positive" it means you when you consider any number, you consider it from the 2s complement point of view and it will either work out as positive or negative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. They should have said it uses a two's complement system, and then given the definition about using 31 bits and, rather than explaining negatives as "two's complement", just explain the bit representation for negatives. Then give their warning about bitwise operators.

Comment: This answer is reasonable. But IMHO would be more accurate to say "32 bits" rather than "31 bits". The most significant bit in Int32 isn't any different than any other bit. It does happen to be useful for indicating sign, but it doesn't indicate sign by itself (i.e. you can't look at the rest of the number after stripping the sign and get the right value). The MSB is an integral part of the entire value, and so any definition of the type should just indicate it uses 32 bits, period.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the question was in relation to the documentation, if you read the wider documentation on the page referenced it talks in terms of 32 bits, the specific paragraph that was referenced is talking about the different parts of the 32 bit value

Comment: Your answer presumes to suggest how the documentation _should_ have been written, so what it currently says is irrelevant. There's no reason to treat the first 31 bits differently from the most significant bit, as none of the bits are meaningful without _all_ the bits. That the documentation currently discusses 31 bits separately doesn't justify stating that it should continue to discuss 31 bits separately.

Comment: @PeterDuniho. I know I have come very late to this Question but I'd like to point out that your statement that the 31 Bits are meaningless without the 32 Bits is wrong. Doesn't the 31 Bits provide distance, if you will, from zero? The direction is irrelevant here you only need the 31 Bits for this. Need to convert from 2's Complement of course. Ok, I'll go now.